# Javascript tokens conversionRates

Tags: node.js

I am currently struggle to get the amount in tokens to wei. I have tried alot of different examples and couldnt got exactly correct results.

This is the most far as I come and with best example:

```
    const getWeiValue = (amount, token) => {
      const conversionRates = {
        btc: '15877852995805999104', 
        eth: '1000000000000000000', 
        dash: '16053258402104000', 
        doge: '38636318585190',
        ltc: '38554269485648000', 
      };

      if (!conversionRates[token]) {
        throw new Error('Unsupported token.');
      }

      const amountBigNumber = new BigNumber(amount);
      const weiValue = amountBigNumber.times(tokenPrice).times(1e18).toFixed(0);

      return weiValue;
    };
```

The only problem is that this is hardcoded and need to be updated almost all the time. The conversation rates have wei / per 1 token ( btc, eth, dash, doge, ltc ).
I have found online the convertor https://www.cryps.info/en/ that have correct values and simpliest way for me is to hard code the wei values.

Is there any simple solution that we can get always the current real wei / per specified token?

Example how its used:

```
    const tokenPrice = await fetchTokenPrice(token.toLowerCase(), 'main');
    const amountInToken = (price_fee / tokenPrice).toFixed(7);
    const weiValue = await getWeiValue(amountInToken, token)
```

price_fee is a total price in usd for example 200 $ it will be 200 and fetchtokenPrice is:

```
    const fetchTokenPrice = async (symbol, network) => {
      const fullName = getCoinFullName(symbol.toLowerCase());

      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${fullName}&vs_currencies=usd`);

        console.log(response.data)

        if (response.data && response.data[fullName] && response.data[fullName].usd) {
          return response.data[fullName].usd;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Invalid response format from CoinGecko API.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching token price:', error);
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch token price.');
      }
    };
```

Best regards.

I had try to based on returned usd price per token get the wei value.